# ASA Transparent Mode Route Lookup

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-asa, firewall

In what situations will an ASA perform route lookup? (transparent mode)

Comment: I don't think it does that except for management traffic if you can call this so.

How did you come on this?

Comment: It does. I have found the question on exam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Primary answer**

The ASA will perform MAC Address lookup when in transparent mode.

It will do Route lookup only for the following reasons;

1. Traffic that originate from the ASA (Syslog for example).
2. Traffic that is one hop away from the ASA with NAT enabled.
3. VoIP and DNS traffic with inspection enabled and endpoint is one hop away from the ASA.

Source: [Cisco's own doc](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/fwmode.html#wp1245468)

---

**Second situation in detail**

Again, source: [Cisco's own doc](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/configuration/guide/cfgnat.html#wp1102744)

[image]

In a nutshell, when the host 192.168.1.2 goes out to reach www.example.com, it will be NATed behind 209.165.201.15.

When the packets come back, the destination is...of course...209.165.201.15. The transparent firewall will "De-Nat" the packet with destination 192.168.1.2.

Since it does not have a MAC address for that specific host (because of the router between the host and the firewall) it will look in it's routing table and send the packets to 10.1.1.3.

Comment: Can you explain 2) in detail?

Comment: What if traffic is one hop away from ASA without NAT enabled.